# How to get bearer token from auth0 Angular

Tags: angular, authentication, auth0, bearer-token

How Should I get the Auth0 bearer token in Angular.
I am currently using Auth0 SDK and AuthModule to set it up.

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ***TOKEN***',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        headers
      }
    });

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

and app.module.ts

```
    @NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I just want to get a way to get bearer token from auth0, I tried implementing getTokenSilently(), didn't work maybe I implemented wrong but I am not sure.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: take a look at the official [Auth0-Angular librray](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular#register-authhttpinterceptor). I suppose it could help you

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this example and source code while dealing with Authorization headers and Tokens.

```
// src/app/auth/secure-interceptor.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, mergeMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SecureInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.url.indexOf('/secure/') > -1) {
      return this.auth.accessToken$.pipe(
        filter(token => typeof token === 'string'),
        mergeMap(token => {
          const tokenReq = req.clone({
            setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
          });
          return next.handle(tokenReq);
        }),
        catchError(err => throwError(err))
      );
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Source - https://kmaida.gitbooks.io/auth0-angular-workshop/content/token-interceptor-service.html

Comment: The example you are referencing doesn't apply here, as the example is of the functions auth.accessToken$ doesn't work and it makes you configure all the login process by yourself instead of taking advantage of the auth0's inbuild functions. I figured it out at last, it is better to use AuthHttpInterceptor instead of making your own.

Comment: Yes you can also use AuthHttpInterceptor to handle all the authentication for which you can refer this [link] (https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use auth0 in an angular application where you are calling api from a backend, I have tried my best to explain it.

This is a service I created to use http requests to the backend, service basically helps to make all the API call through 1 file.

Admin.service.ts

```
   @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
    export class AdminService {
    
        equipment= []
    
        constructor(
            private http: HttpClient, 
        
            ) {
        }
    
        equipmentlist(){
            this.equipment.length = 0;
            this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/admin/equipmentlist`).toPromise().then(data => {
            for(let key in data)
                    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key))
                        this.equipment.push(data[key]);
    
            });
    
            return this.equipment;
        }
}
```

and app.module.ts

```
enum CacheStorage {
  LocalStorage = "localStorage",
  SessionStorage = "sessionStorage"
}

      @NgModule({
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
      imports: [
     AuthModule.forRoot({ 
    ...env.auth,
    cacheLocation: 'localstorage',
     // The AuthHttpInterceptor configuration
    ...env.authapi,
    }),
      ],
      providers: [
       AuthGuard,
       Validators,
       { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthHttpInterceptor,  multi: true }
      ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Dont forget to configure your enviornment.ts file so the entire thing works compelete.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: "https://localhost:7004",
    auth:{
      domain:  ,
      clientId: ,
      scope:,
      redirectUri: ,
      apiUrl:"https://localhost:7004/",
      audience: ,
      useRefreshTokens: true,
  },
  authapi:{
    httpInterceptor: {
      allowedList: [
        // YOUR backend API - specifically the protected ones 
        'https://localhost:7004/admin/*'
        ],
    }
  },
```

You can find more related article on Auth0's Docs I personally didn't find it very useful but they are extensive and gradually it does start making sense.